# Repeat Columns of equation across rows infinitely

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, repeat

In Google Sheets, is there a way I can repeat columns of equations across rows laterally??

In [Pic1][image: 1], I have a set of data from A1:C (in red color), listing out employee no., name and salary.

Below is the equations in yellow to show data in A10 `=QUERY($A$2:$C$7,"Order by A Desc")`, the equation in D10 is to multiple employee salary by 2 times `=C10:C*2`

Is there a way / any forumula I can type to keep on repeating A9:D set of equations across rows laterally like in [Pic2][image: 2] (yellow)?

Manually copying and pasting across rows is very troublesome if copied in large amounts. It would be great is there is a formula way to achieve that.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concat multiple arrays horizontally, we can use array literals `{arr1,arr2}`. To automate this process, we can use `REDUCE` to loop and accumulate the `arr` multiple times:

```
=REDUCE(arr,SEQUENCE(number_of_times_to_repeat-1),LAMBDA(a,c,{a,arr}))
```

#### Sample:

To repeat `A9:D` three times,

```
=REDUCE(A9:D,SEQUENCE(2),LAMBDA(a,c,{a,A9:D}))
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
={A9:D, A9:D, A9:D, A9:D}
```

[image]